# Click and pylint

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint, python-click

Here is a simple example of *click* usage that causes pylint error:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--option', is_flag=True)
def foo(option):
    click.echo(option)

foo()
```

`foo` receives no arguments so I'm getting E1120 (no-value-for-parameter).
So I did this:

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--option', is_flag=True)
def foo(**kwargs):
    click.echo(kwargs["option"])

foo()
```

Is there a better way?
Or a way to disable pylint for only one line in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `@click.command` decorator edits your functions parameters, but pylint does not know this, since it does not actually run your code.

I don't think it makes sense to make your code weird just so pylint is happy. Instead, ignore it, or add a comment to disable that warning in the current scope:

```
# pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But is there a way to apply this exception only for one line / file in VSC?

Comment: Yes, add this comment to the end of the line

Comment: Wow! I didn't get it at first.

Comment: Is there a way to tell pylint to _always_ disable no-value-for-parameter when checking @click-decorated functions? (So I don't have to do this in every single script.)

Comment: not as far as I know. You can globally disable no-value-for-parameter, but that sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: For future reference: the underlying problem with pylint: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/259

Answer (score 10):

Meanwhile, the [pylint authors have added](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/2926/files#diff-9b76776694be02a09ca25a56adee0b3087ad5b86dfafd318923c4bf008c131c3R766) a way to deal with this: the `signature-mutators` setting.

This should tell pylint that click mutates function signatures, and
that it should look a bit deeper:

```
# .pylintrc
...
signature-mutators=click.decorators.option
```

`pylint` checks if the name/qualified-name of a called function's decorators is in the `signature-mutators` list.  Therefor, we can't use `click.option` , for that is an alias, but we have to use the *declared* name.

To be complete, I *think* we could add all decorators found in `click/decorators.py`:

```
[TYPECHECK]
signature-mutators=click.decorators.option,
                   click.decorators.argument,
                   click.decorators.version_option,
                   click.decorators.help_option,
                   click.decorators.pass_context,
                   click.decorators.confirmation_option
```

Note: this setting *needs* to be under the `[TYPECHECK]` section.
(thanks, @Federico Corazza)

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to avoid those errors from happening, by not using the decoration syntax. This might be what @Azsgy referred to as 'weird' :-)

```
@click.option(
    "--direction",
    default="upgrade",
    type=click.Choice(["upgrade", "downgrade"]),
    help="Direction of migration upgrade/downgrade",
)
@click.argument("revision", default="heads")
def _main(direction, revision):
    """Runs migrations on each of the databases."""
    pass


main = click.command()(_main)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Whether it's nice or not is debatable :-)

Answer (score 2):

@xtofl's solution works. Just be mindful that the options should be below a header called `TYPECHECK`:

```
[TYPECHECK]
signature-mutators=click.decorators.option,
                   click.decorators.argument,
                   click.decorators.version_option,
                   click.decorators.help_option,
                   click.decorators.pass_context,
                   click.decorators.confirmation_option
```

Probably others have proposed an edit addressing this because if I try to modify @xtofl's solution I get "Suggested edit queue is full".

Comment: Thanks, you're right.  I even experienced it the hard way.  Now we have two, near-identical answers.  If you would have posted a comment, I could have edited it :).  The Suggested edit queue didn't apparently contain any proposals for my answer.

Comment: @xtofl At the time I didn't have enough reputation to comment on other people's answers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pyproject.toml here's the correct syntax to @xtofl solution:

```py
[tool.pylint.typecheck]
signature-mutators=['click.decorators.option',
                    'click.decorators.argument',
                    'click.decorators.version_option',
                    'click.decorators.help_option',
                    'click.decorators.pass_context',
                    'click.decorators.confirmation_option'
]
```